# Python: for-loop wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, output

Can't understand why it missing some indexes in loop?
Index number 3 for example.
I just want to delete the unique elements this way. I know another one but I don't know what's wrong with this one (or me).

```
lst = [2, 7, 1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 1]

def check(lst):
    result = lst
    print(lst) #checking
    for num in lst:
        print("index:", num) #checking
        print("num:", num) #checking
        if lst.count(num) < 2:
            print("count:", lst.count(num)) #checking
            result.remove(num)
    return(result)

print(check(lst))
```

Output

```
[2, 7, 1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 1]
index: 2
num: 2
index: 7
num: 7
count: 1
index: 9
num: 9
count: 1
index: 5
num: 5
count: 1
index: 1
num: 1
[2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: not mutate a list as you iterate over it!!!!

Comment: I think you may be looking for [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). Also, **never mutate a list while iterating over it**. It results in bad, bad things....

Comment: You are removing elements from the list as you are iterating through it. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it keeps the index intact during a remove, which means if the index points to element number 4, and you delete number 4, all the elements to the right shift one to the left, then the index increments, thereby skipping one element. A better way would be to keep a list of items to remove, then remove them after this loop.

Comment: Thank you all! I forgot that result is just a mirror (not copy) of the lst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing items from a list *as you're iterating over it*, which you shouldn't do.

(`result = lst` does NOT make a copy of `lst`; it creates a new *name* which refers to the same object.)

If you just want to remove duplicate elements, you can use a `set` (although you may lose your ordering):

```
lst = list(set(lst))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to note how he **_can_** make a copy of the list(`result = lst[:]`)?

Comment: this should really be a comment not an answer  ...